# Получение значения в сервисе (RxJS)

Tags: angular, rxjs

создаю независимый сервис, который будет выдавать наружу параметры поиска через Observable.  как в данном случае выдавать наружу значения параметра поиска через Observable из сервиса

https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-g34gj

```js
export class SearchInputComponent implements OnInit {

 searchInput: FormControl = new FormControl();

 constructor(public searchFilterService: SearchFilterService) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }

 onSearch() {
  this.searchFilterService.emitSearchFilter(this.searchInput.value.trim());
 }

 clearSearch() {
  this.searchFilterService.emitSearchFilter(this.searchInput.setValue(''));
 }
  
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput
     (keyup.enter)="onSearch()"
     [formControl]="searchInput"
     name="search">
       <mat-icon matSuffix
     *ngIf="searchInput.value"
     (click)="clearSearch()">
  close
 </mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

`SearchFilterService`

```
private searchParams = new BehaviorSubject<SearchFilter>(null);
changeSearchParams$: Observable<SearchFilter> = this.searchParams.asObservable();

emitSearchFilter(x: any) {
   this.searchParams.next(x);
}
```

```
export interface SearchFilter {
    value: string;
}
```

Comment: Создай пожалуйста _воспроизводимый пример_ на codesandbox :)

Comment: @overthesanity, не получается сделать воспроизводимый пример(( https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-g34gj

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду на codesandbox, проблема в том что сервис инжектится как провайдер в компонент `providers: [SearchFilterService]`.

В этом случае для компонента будет создан отдельный инстанс `SearchFilterService`.

Если убрать строчку `providers: [SearchFilterService]` из объявлений компонентов, то будет создан инстанс `SearchFilterService` на уровне приложение. Это должно помочь.